# Errors using ssh config file

Tags: powershell, ssh

I am trying to make a config file so I don't have to type the longhand command to ssh into a server.

When I try and use a ~/.ssh/config file to ssh into my server in place of the standard ssh {path_to_key} {user}:{ip} (or however its formatted) command, I keep getting an error saying no hosts found. I tried adding an alias to my hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc by giving it my IP and specifying the alias name but that doesn't include my pem key so it doesnt work either. Here is my config file:
Host cloud-control
HostName xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
User ubuntu
Port 22
IdentityFile "path"

Yes, the path and HostName are correct. I am able to ssh using the longhand command.

Comment: You need a "path_to_key" which is a directory (not just a server).  Network drives on located on a server so you need the server name and driver like : \\MyServer\c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc.  If you are an Admin you may need to replace the colon with a dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

So in my particular case, my issue was simply that my config file had a type of txt. Its a very easy thing to overlook. If you are having trouble removing the txt type of your file, click the view tab in file explorer and look for the "show extentions" option. Enable it, and click on your file name to remove the extention.

openSSH apparently isn't looking for a txt file. Its specifically looking for a config file with no type. Despite this, it is able to handle text files if you use the longhand version of the ssh command which is why you may be able to use the longhand version but not the alias version.

Comment: To be specific, this is the file's extension, not the file's type.  Windows, for some reason, tries to hide the file extensions, apparently because they think they will frighten users.  It causes difficult to find mistakes like this.